# Default values for query params structure in Go Fiber

Tags: rest, go, go-fiber

Is there a way to set default values to query params when mapping them to a struct in Fiber?
I need to bind query params to a struct in Fiber using **QueryParser** and then validate that struct using **github.com/go-playground/validator**.
I have a following struct:

```
type PaginationQuery struct {
    Page int `query:"page" default:"1" validate:"gt=0"`
    Size int `query:"size" default:"10" validate:"gt=0"`
    SortBy string `query:"sortBy" default:"name" validate:"oneof=id name country"`
}
```

And here is the binding:

```
var pagination payload.PaginationQuery
    
if err := c.QueryParser(&pagination); err != nil {
    return fiber.NewError(fiber.StatusInternalServerError, "Something went wrong")
}

if err := service.validator.Struct(&pagination); err != nil {
    return fiber.NewError(fiber.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
}

// validation failes
```

As you can see from the code above, I am using the `default` tag, but it doesn't work, still receiving nil values(0, 0, "").
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The `default` tag is not natively supported by the Go `validate` package. Check this out: https://github.com/go-playground/validator/issues/263